Excel table with running total based on two different columns
I'm very close to getting what I need, which is a running total based on criteria in three columns.
Thanks to this website: https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/running-totals-excel-tables/, I was able to get:

Running total (Column D): =SUM(tblSales[[#Headers],[Amount]]:[@Amount])
Running total by region (Column E): =SUMIF(tblSales[[#Headers],[Region]]:[@Region],[@Region],tblSales[[#Headers],[Amount]]:[@Amount])

What I'm struggling with is:

Running total by region & description - I tried using SUMIFS (Column F): =SUMIFS(tblSales[[#Headers],[Amount]]:[@Amount],[@Region],[@Region],[@Description],[@Description]), but I'm getting a #VALUE! error.
My ultimate goal is for Column G to show a running total by region, by description and by date (oldest to newest).

In Column H below, I show the desired results and highlighted the most recent balance for each grouping. I don't want to go the pivot table route.
Thank you in advance!


When using SUMIF, notice the sum_range argument comes last:

When using SUMIFS, notice the sum_range argument comes first:

So you have to move your tblSales[[#Headers],[Amount]]:[@Amount] argument to the beginning of your formula, like so:
=SUMIFS(tblSales[[#Headers],[Amount]]:[@Amount],tblSales[[#Headers],[Region]]:[@Region],[@Region],tblSales[[#Headers],[Description]]:[@Description],[@Description])



this is terrific! With your help, I was also able to add a third criteria for date and it works brilliantly. Thank you so much!
